# When querying blob from db, how do I convert the blob to text in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, search, blob

I am trying to create a search function for a client and they have a field in an existing table that they set up as a blob. When I query the table in my search script below I get the following results from three fields:

FIELDS:

```
1-item_num
2-info (blob)
3-name
```

Query:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_products
    WHERE (`item_num` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`info` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

(RESULTS)

```
22 (name)
penlite (item_num)
PHA+MiBBQSBBbm9kaXplZCBBbHVtaW51bSBwZW5saXRlIDwvcD4= (info)
```

How do I convert the blob into readable text on my search results page?

Comment: what do you mean by readable? Why can't you just echo the result?

Comment: Why are you doing a text search against some binary data? How was the data encoded/encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_products
    WHERE (`item_num` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (CONVERT(`info` USING utf8) LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```